# Can't send requests to ipv6 adresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, unix, ubuntu, curl

I have a outdated version of `ubuntu` distro, version `10.10` and i currently can't upgrade it.

I have a problem making any kind of http requests to ipv6 adresses. I tried to do it with various Ruby gem libraries such as `open-uri`, `Rest-client`, and with `curl`.

When i send out a request i get a `Network unreachable` response. To be specific, i am sending out requests to `https://graph.facebook.com` with the `Koala gem`.

If i try to do it with

```
curl -4 http://graph.facebook.com
```

i get a proper response, and everything is fine.

Is there a solution that i could do so i can globally solve this problem, maybe modify `unix` config file?

I have searched a lot around the web and haven't been able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried connecting to other networks and it worked.

At last i called my ISP and they set my modem to factory settings and updated the software.

Now everything seems to work fine.